# How to replace non-diagonal elements in a matrix?

Tags: r, replace, diagonal

More specifically, I want all elements other than the diagonal ones (X_11, X_22, X_33,...,X_jj) to be zero.

E.g. I want:

```
 [1 4 5
  2 3 5
  3 9 8]
```

to be:

```
 [1 0 0
  0 3 0
  0 0 8]
```

Is this possible? Sorry I'm a complete noob at this..

Comment: What programming language? What context? As it currently stands it's hard to tell what you're asking here, are implementations in any language ok?

Comment: @PLB The community here also strongly condemns discouraging new people. Please use better words to quote your thoughts.

Comment: @loxxy: The community (if you'd like to call it that) isn't a homework machine. If you have an interesting problem, someone might be able to help you. In this case, there is no problem. There's a straightforward task and no attempt (at least from what OP mentioned in the post).

Comment: @loxxy What do you mean in _better words_? I have not said anything bad, IMO.

Comment: @Blender Well, my bad to think the OP could even be a little kid for whom this definitely could be an interesting problem.

Comment: @PLB Sorry for not considering noob, a better word & overlooking that OP himself mentioned the same.

Comment: sorry, I just realized how useless my question was...I'm working in R, and when I simply use the diag() function it just extracts the diagonal elements from the matrix and gives me a 1xn vector.
I imagine I should utilize the replace() function somehow, maybe use the logic "if not diagonal" or something like that but I have no idea how...

Answer (score 3):

It's a simple one liner. First, get the data in:

```
> (a <- matrix(scan(),nr=3,byrow=TRUE))
1: 1 4 5 2 3 5 3 9 8
10: 
Read 9 items
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    5
[2,]    2    3    5
[3,]    3    9    8
```

Method 1:

```
> diag(diag(a))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    3    0
[3,]    0    0    8
```

The thing is, if its argument is a matrix, `diag` *extracts* the diagonal... but if the argument is a vector, it's a function that *creates* a diagonal matrix. So just use it twice. (In fact `diag` has *four* different uses, depending on what you give it, though two of the cases are quite similar.) See `?diag`

If your matrices are huge this isn't likely to be the most efficient way, but for moderate size cases that's the way I do it.

---

Method 2:

A completely different one-liner that also works -

```
ifelse(row(a)==col(a),a,0)
```

The two work the same on square matrices. But they have a different result on non-square matrices - the first one returns a square matrix (of dimension the smaller of the two original dimensions), while the second one returns an object of the same shape as its argument; this can be useful depending on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this, is to create a new matrix filled with 0s, then replace its diagonal with the diagonal of the old matrix.

So if you have:

```
m <- cbind(c(1,2,3), c(4,3,9), c(5, 5, 8))  # The original matrix

diagonal <- diag(m)
m <- matrix(0, nrow(m), ncol(m))  # Overwrite the old matrix
diag(m) <- diagonal
```

Answer (score 1):

For a matrix of n x m

```
for i to n
    for j to m
        if i != j
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
```

Comment: Now that this question is tagged [tag:r], I'd consider your answer not too helpful. Firstly, the syntax does not match, and secondly, writing explicit loops in this fashion is bad for performance.

Comment: True, But this answer can still pass as the algo for the problem, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

If `m` is your matrix try:

```
m = matrix(c(1,4,5,2,3,5,3,9,8),3,3)
m[upper.tri(m) | lower.tri(m)] = 0

m

##      [,1] [,2] [,3]
## [1,]    1    0    0
## [2,]    0    3    0
## [3,]    0    0    8
```

Answer (score 0):

It simply dependes on the size of the matrix you're dealing with, let's say you have a **nxn** matrix then the diagonals are gonna be at these places 0, n+1 , 2(n+1), 3(n+1),... if your matrix as you mentioned is not multi dimensional and is linear! so by simply writing a for loop it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

*I'm transferring [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706741/1468366) from [your second post on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16706578/1468366).*

You can use the following to compute a logical matrix which describes the non-diagonal entries of a `n`×`n` matrix:

```
outer(1:n, 1:n, function(i,j) i!=j)
```

Applied to your example:

```
> m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,3,9,5,5,8),ncol=3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    5
[2,]    2    3    5
[3,]    3    9    8
> m[outer(1:3, 1:3, function(i,j) i!=j)] <- 0
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    3    0
[3,]    0    0    8
```

I also like the [triangle approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706289/1468366) by [@e4e5f4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2202762/e4e5f4). That might be a bit faster than this code here, but this code here might be easier to adapt to different situations. So it's good to know this one, even if that one might be preferrable for your current application.