# Replacing non-diagonal elements in a matrix in R (hopefully a better asked this time)

Tags: r, replace

Okay, I asked this question earlier but I got bashed (deservedly) for not specifying anything and showing no sign of previous attempt. So let me try again..

I'm using R, and I have a 463✕463 matrix. What I would like to do is to replace all elements other than the diagonal ones (X<sub>11</sub>, X<sub>22</sub>, X<sub>33</sub>,...,X<sub>jj</sub>) with zero.

E.g. I want:

```
[1 4 5
 2 3 5
 3 9 8]
```

to be:

```
[1 0 0
 0 3 0
 0 0 8]
```

When I use the `diag()` function, it simply gives me a column vector of the diagonal values. I imagine I can use the `replace()` function somehow combined with a "if not diagonal" logic...but I am lost.

And yes, as some here have guessed, I am probably much younger than many people here and am completely new at this...so please put me in the right direction. Really appreciate all your help!

Comment: Be sure to tag your questions with the language that you're using.   After I tagged the other one as r, you got some better answers.

Comment: In situations where [your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16705468/1468366) is ill-written, it is usually better to edit that question in an attempt to improve it, instead of simply starting off with a new question.

Answer (score 4):

In R, the `diag` method has two functions.

1. It **returns** the diagonal of a matrix. I.e.

   ```
   m <- matrix(1:9, ncol=3)
   m
   #      [,1] [,2] [,3]
   # [1,]    1    4    7
   # [2,]    2    5    8
   # [3,]    3    6    9
   diag(m)
   # [1] 1 5 9
   ```
2. It can **construct** a diagonal matrix.

   ```
   diag(1:3)
   #      [,1] [,2] [,3]
   # [1,]    1    0    0
   # [2,]    0    2    0
   # [3,]    0    0    3
   ```

So in your case, extract the diagonal from your existing matrix and supply it to `diag`:

```
diag(diag(m))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    5    0
# [3,]    0    0    9
```

Answer (score 2):

Examples using logical indexing:

```
# Case 1
m[ col(m)==row(m) ] <- 0  # replaces diagonal elements with 0

# Case 2
m <- matrix(1:9, 3)   # create example
m[ col(m)==row(m) ]   # displaya diagonal elements
#[1] 1 5 9 

# Case 3 uses diag(3) to create a logical matrix 
 # transparent indexing rule
m <- matrix(1:9, 3)   # create example
m[ !diag(3) ] <- 0  # negation of 1's on diagonal coerces to logical

# Case 4
# more transparently
m <- matrix(1:9, 3)   # create example
m[ col(m)!=row(m) ] <- 0  # set non-diagonal elements to 0
m                      # show results
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    5    0
[3,]    0    0    9
```

Answer (score 1):

## using outer

You can use the following to compute a logical matrix which describes the non-diagonal entries of a `n`×`n` matrix:

```
outer(1:n, 1:n, function(i,j) i!=j)
```

Applied to your example:

```
> m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,3,9,5,5,8),ncol=3)
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    4    5
[2,]    2    3    5
[3,]    3    9    8
> m[outer(1:3, 1:3, function(i,j) i!=j)] <- 0
> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    3    0
[3,]    0    0    8
```

## using triangles

A possible alternative would be combining the two triangles on either side of the diagonal. In this case, you use the matrix `m` itself as input to determine the size.

```
upper.tri(m) | lower.tri(m)
```

Applied to your use case:

```
> m[upper.tri(m) | lower.tri(m)] <- 0
```

It seems you already [got this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16706289/1468366) in response to [your original post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16705468/1468366)…

Comment: Both methods worked out perfectly! Thank you!!