# Replacing off-diagonal elements with a fixed value

Tags: r, matrix, dplyr, pipe, diagonal

I have a `square matrix` and now I want to replace all its off-diagonal elements with a fixed value. Some approaches how this can be done are discussed in [Replacing non-diagonal elements in a matrix in R (hopefully a better asked this time)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16706578/replacing-non-diagonal-elements-in-a-matrix-in-r-hopefully-a-better-asked-this)

For example,

```
m <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,3,9,5,5,8),ncol=3)
m[upper.tri(m) | lower.tri(m)] <- 999
m
```

I am wondering if the step can be performed using `dplyr chain rule`, something like

```
library(dplyr)
matrix(c(1,2,3,4,3,9,5,5,8),ncol=3) %>%
 ### add this -> m[upper.tri(m) | lower.tri(m)] <- 999
```

Any pointer will be very helpful

Answer (score 4):

If it's for the sake of brevity, you could define + apply an anonymous function in your pipeline like so:

```
matrix(c(1,2,3,4,3,9,5,5,8),ncol=3) %>%
  (\(.) {.[upper.tri(.) | lower.tri(.)] = 999; .})() %>%
## rest of pipeline
```

**Edit**
shamelessly <s>stealing</s> borrowing from @Maël 's elegant solution:

```
matrix(c(1,2,3,4,3,9,5,5,8),ncol=3) %>%
  ifelse(row(.) == col(.), ., 999) %>%
## rest of pipeline
```

(note: does not work with the native pipe operator `|>`)

Answer (score 4):

For large enough `m` and `n`, it is much more efficient to initialize the `m`-by-`n` result with all elements equal to `r` and replace only the diagonal elements:

```r
m <- 1000L
n <- 1000L
r <- -1L
x <- diag(seq_len(min(m, n)), m, n)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    A = x |> (\(.) `diag<-`(array(r, dim(.), dimnames(.)), diag(., names = FALSE)))(),
    B = x |> (\(.) `[<-`(., row(.) != col(.), r))(),
    C = x |> (\(.) `[<-`(., upper.tri(.) | lower.tri(.), r))(),
    times = 1000L)
```

```
Unit: microseconds
 expr      min         lq       mean    median        uq      max neval
    A   67.445   283.2075   520.3644   315.823   343.498 12723.82  1000
    B 4475.232  5024.3450  5750.4401  5479.527  6081.837 16821.36  1000
    C 8863.134 10034.4835 11035.8599 10535.052 11030.066 22211.34  1000
```

Answer (score 3):

With `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(row(m) == col(m), m, 999)
```

Or with `replace`:

```r
m %>% 
  replace(row(.) != col(.), 999)
```

```r
m %>%
  replace(. != diag(.), 999)
```

```r
m |>
  replace(m != diag(m), 999)
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use

```
matrix(c(1,2,3,4,3,9,5,5,8),ncol=3) %>%
   `[<-`(upper.tri(.) | lower.tri(.), 999)
```

-output

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1  999  999
[2,]  999    3  999
[3,]  999  999    8
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try pipes like below

```
matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 9, 5, 5, 8), ncol = 3) %>%
  {
    999 * (!diag(nrow(.))) + diag(.)
  }
```